# Unset php session variable

Tags: php, ajax, session, post, unset

I'm passing an id by ajax to be removed by $_SESSION. The ajax part works fine, the php receive in POST the id, but the vairable can't be unset. Why??? Here my code:

The ajax part:

```
    $(".delete").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_to_remove = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(id_to_remove);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/functions/remove_item_from_cart.php',
        data: { id : id_to_remove },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#content").load('inc/functions/get_checkout_content.php');
            alert(data);
        }
    })

});
```

The php receiving part:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
//echo var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
$ncart=$_SESSION['cart'];
if (count($ncart)>0){
    unset($ncart[$_POST['id']]); // this is NOT working!!!
    $ncart=array_values($ncart);

    $_SESSION['cart']=$ncart;
    if(count($ncart)==0){
        unset($_SESSION['cart']);
        unset($_SESSION['cart_total']);
        echo "all_empty";
    } // this if part is the only working!
}
}
```

Any helpful suggestion why I can't unset the session variable? Thanks!

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work with this code? We won't guess what's going wrong...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is now deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, but just to confirm, is this process correct: `$ncart=$_SESSION['cart'];` to `$ncart=array_values($ncart);` to `$_SESSION['cart']=$ncart;`?

Comment: i suspect you must change if(count($ncart)==0)  to if(count($_SESSION['cart'])==0)

Comment: @MichaelRushton That just re-numbers the keys in that array to be consecutive after removing one from the middle. It's necessary because of the unusual but powerful nature of PHP's "array" type as simultaneously list/vector and (ordered) hash.

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta Those two if statements will behave exactly the same, since one variable has been written to the other on the line before.

Comment: @IMSoP, I had a moment of insanity and read `array_values` as `array_keys`. Red-face moment.

Comment: So anybody has any idea how to make it works? I have already used this script and it has worked fine untill now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my own solution:

```
if (count($_SESSION['cart'])>0){

 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $subarray){ 
  if ($subarray['id'] == $_POST['id']){ 
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]); 
 break; 
 } 
} 

$_SESSION['cart'] = array_values($_SESSION['cart']);

} else {
 if(count($_SESSION['cart'])==0){
  unset($_SESSION['cart']);
  unset($_SESSION['cart_total']);
  echo "all_empty";
 }  
}
```

That's because the array was like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Collier Ano petit
            [price] => 45
            [quant] => 1
            [ptotal] => 45
        )

)
```